# Race condition in Producer-Consumer: limit notifications to when condition variable is waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, producer-consumer

I've implemented a simple Producer-Consumer message queue.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>


#define MESSAGE_QUIT 1


struct MessageQueue
{
    std::deque<int> message_ids;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition_variable;
};


void SleepFor(int time_in_millis)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time_in_millis));
}


void ProcessMessage(int message_id)
{
    std::cout << "Processing Message #" << message_id << '\n';
}


void Producer(MessageQueue *messages)
{
    for (int message_id = 10; message_id >= MESSAGE_QUIT; --message_id) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(messages->mutex);    
        messages->message_ids.push_back(message_id);            
        guard.unlock();
        messages->condition_variable.notify_one();
        SleepFor(200);
    }
}


void Consumer(MessageQueue *messages)
{
    int next_message_id = -1;

    while (next_message_id != MESSAGE_QUIT) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(messages->mutex);
        messages->condition_variable.wait(guard);
        next_message_id = messages->message_ids.front();
        messages->message_ids.pop_front();
        guard.unlock();
        ProcessMessage(next_message_id);
    }
}


int main()
{
    MessageQueue messages;

    std::thread producer_thread(&Producer, &messages);
    std::thread consumer_thread(&Consumer, &messages);

    producer_thread.join();
    consumer_thread.join();
}
```

The race condition: in some cases, the condition variable is calling `notify_one()` in the producer thread while it is not in the waiting state in the consumer thread. How would you solve this? I am not considering the case of spurious waking for now.

Comment: Have you considered processing the ids with a `while(!messages->message_ids.empty()) {...}` instead ?

Comment: @moooeeeep First I'd like to point out a simple edit I made, which I don't believe is relevant to the question you asked: I removed the check for the empty queue after the `wait()` call. Second, I don't think that your suggestion necessarily solves the problem. What if the queue is empty, but we still need to wait for messages? The loop will exit while messages are added in the producer. Am I missing something? This seems like a possibility given the non-deterministic nature of threads.

Comment: What, exactly, goes wrong when someone calls `notify_one` when nobody is waiting?  Is it that messages are in the queue and nobody picks them up?  That isn't a problem with `notify_one`, but rather with how you are waiting on the condition variable.

Comment: @Yakk in my specific implementation, the consumer message loop never receives the quit message, and so the last message received is ID 3 or 2. This is because `notify_one` is called exactly 10 times.

Comment: @nasser-sh So your problem is that messages are not being picked up, not `notify_one` being called before `wait` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition variables can spuriously wake up.

```
messages->condition_variable.wait(guard)
```

So don't do this.  There are other reasons to not do this, including the fact that you can wait on a condition variable when there is data ready.

```
messages->condition_variable.wait(guard, [&]{return !messages->message_ids().empty();)
```

This won't wait if there are already messages in the queue.  It also deals with spurious wakeups.

Comment: Ok, I've added this change to my implementation and it seems to have fixed the problem... but I'm confused why. Isn't there still a race condition? Isn't it possible for `notify_one()` to be called twice, before the first `wait()` call?

Comment: @nasser-sh Yes, but why do you care?  Nobody waits on an empty queue.

Comment: 'Doh! Ok, I see how this works now. Indeed, the problem was pinpointed in your answer: the loop is waiting while there is data ready. Thanks!